# Not able to sudo - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, sudo

A classical error

By mistake we did `sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /` on a ubuntu 20.04 AWS EC2 server.  While there are many posts which indicates that I cannot salvage the machine and have to reinstall a new one - I want to take a copy of the postgres that runs on this server. Currently We could not do any command with a sudo.  Hence we could not start postgres or login through phppgadmin.

We have done the following:

1. Stopped the instance
2. Detached the volume
3. Created a new instance
4. Attached the volume
5. Mounted the volume
6. Changed to root in the new instance
7. did `chown -R root:root /mnt/rescue` (changed this to `root:ubuntu`, `ubuntu:ubuntu`, etc)
8. did `chmod -R 4755 /mnt/rescue` (also did `0755`, `ug-s`, etc)
9. Exited root
10. `umount /mnt/rescue`
11. Shut the rescue instance
12. Detach the volume
13. Attach the volume to the corrupted machine.  The machine indicates the new owner - but sudo not working.
14. We tried creating a new instance - attaching this corrected volume, updated /etc/fstab - reboot the instance.  We got the volume merged with the machine.  After reboot - still the same issue - not able to sudo.

We can certainly re-create the machine or take the back up and restore. However, some mission critical data is residing in the postgres.  How do I sudo, or retrieve files from a dead postgres.

We are constantly facing the error:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

however, when I do ls -l anywhere from inside /usr or /usr/bin - the entire ownership of all the file remains with ubuntu:ubuntu or other combinations that we have tried.

Comment: Just copy the files? This is pretty trivial.

Comment: Which files of postgres?

Comment: The whole data directory.

Comment: When I checked for data dir - i got this path `/var/lib/postgresql/13/main`  do you mean this directory?

Comment: Yes, if that's where your system kept the files, then that's what you want to copy.

Comment: Many thanks...I will try this one and post the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the setuid bit and make it executable for root, which is the default permission (rws) for sudo

```
chmod u+s /mnt/rescue/usr/bin/sudo
chmod +x /mnt/rescue/usr/bin/sudo
```

While this could be useful to resuce the system, there are many other files and directories which have different such permissions and ownerships, and setting them individually can be tedious.